# How to use FUTURA-Bold font in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uifont

I am trying to use FUTURA-BOld in my app but its not working as it should be. I installed the font in my system, copied the font in my code resource. Edited the info.plist with the font name. And choosing the same font but it is just giving me simple font.

Any idea ???

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

1) Have you made the plist entry `UIAppFonts` of type array, putting your (ttf) filename as a member value?

2) Are you using the actual internal font name? This may differ from the ttf filename. Use

```
NSLog(@"fonts: %@",[UIFont familyNames]);
```

to get a list of fonts. Lookup your font and use that name exactly.

Comment: When i am checking for the available font name i don't get FUTURA-Bold.

Comment: When i am checking for the available font name i don't get FUTURA-Bold.I am using this to view the available fonts and it doesn't give me futura bold                                                 NSArray * fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"FUTURA"];
NSLog(@"%@",fontNames);

Comment: You should use what I posted, not `fontNamesForFamilyName`. Because the font name probably is *not* FUTURA.

Comment: I just did this and there is only one Futura in the list. No Futura Medium.  However I am able to use Futura Medium 19 from storyboard, just not programmatically.